# Arrows layout to go around classes, tikz uml

Tags: tikz-uml

I've this code in tikz uml.

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=3em]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-4,y=3]{B} {
    \umlvirt{+ method() : void}} {
}

\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-2,y=-3]{C} {
    \umlvirt{+ method() : void}} {
}

\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-2,y=-5]{D}
{
    \umlvirt{+ method() : int}}
    {
}

\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-2,y=-9]{E} {
    \umlvirt{+ method() : void}
    }
    {
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east]{B}{E}
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east]{B}{D}
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east]{B}{C}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And basically I can't manage to let the dashed lines to go around the classes. Something like the following

[image]

I thought that specifiying the following would've allowed me to achieve the layout I wanted to but it doesn't work

```
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east]{B}{E}
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east]{B}{D}
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east]{B}{C}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to find out exactly what `tikz-uml` does, but you can set the `arm1` parameter of `\umldep` to appropriate values. When you define a three segment connection like `-|-`, the length of the first and last segment can be set with `arm1` and `arm2`, respectively.

I couldn't find a way of starting the dependency line on some random position along the border of a class, so I defined two helper coordinates instead, and used those as the starting point of the dependency line.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[
  tikz,
%  14pt, % not a valid option in standard classes (which standalone uses)
  border=10pt
]{standalone}
%\usepackage{verbatim} not used in this example
%\usepackage{tikz} loaded by tikz-uml
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
%\usepackage{xcolor} loaded by tikz
%\usepackage{pgf-umlsd} not used

% none of the remaining preamble is used
%\usetikzlibrary{er}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

%\tikzset{ % recommended over \tikzstyle
%  int/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=3em},
%  init/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-4,y=2]{B} {
    \umlvirt{+ method() : void}} {
}

\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-2,y=0]{C} {
    \umlvirt{+ method() : void}} {
}

\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-2,y=-3]{D}
{
    \umlvirt{+ method() : int}}
    {
}

\umlclass[rectangle split parts=2,x=-2,y=-5]{E} {
    \umlvirt{+ method() : void}
    }
    {
}

% define coordinates 5mm above/below the east point of B
\coordinate (B1) at ([yshift=5mm]B.east);
\coordinate (B2) at ([yshift=-5mm]B.east);


% note that B1 and B2 are used here
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east,arm1=4cm]{B1}{E}
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east,arm1=3.25cm]{B}{D}
\umldep[geometry=-|-,anchor1=east,anchor2=east,arm1=2.5cm]{B2}{C}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, as you're just drawing a line with a specific style (`tikzuml dependency style`), you could do

```
\draw [tikzuml dependency style] ([yshift=3mm]B.east) -- ++(4cm,0) |- (E.east);
\draw [tikzuml dependency style] (B.east) -- ++(3.25cm,0) |- (D.east);
\draw [tikzuml dependency style] ([yshift=-3mm]B.east) -- ++(2.5cm,0) |- (C.east);
```

Comment: Does this work for other kind of relationships? like `umlcompo` for example and the others.

Comment: @user8469759 I would think so. Looks like all the different relations use the same underlying macro, `\umlrelation`. The only difference between them is that different styles are used. I.e. `\umldep` is basically `\umlrelation[tikzuml dependency style]`, `\umlcompo` is basically `\umlrelation[tikzuml composition style]`, etc.

Comment: What's the meaning of `arm1` and `arm2`?

Comment: @user8469759 Did you read the first paragraph of my answer?

Comment: @user8469759 You can always delete your own comments I think, hover the cursor over a 
comment, and an "x" appears to the right of it.